# D - friendlier asm syntactic sugar for GDC (Dlang)

Tags: d, inline-assembly, gdc

I had an idea to ease the process of creating D plus asm code using GDC's extended asm syntax. I'd like to get rid of the need to insert \n\t markers all over the place by, say, having separate strings and getting the D compiler to concatenate them. But I'm open to other suggestions. My attempt failed, because  concatenating D strings unfortunately doesn't work in GDC *at compile-time* and I need CTFE. It's a requirement, as you'd expect, that this piece of sugar has zero cost.

I need to do something with mixin, I suspect. Any tips on where to go and how to stay within CTFE?

Comment: There are several string styles like `q{...}`, backticks which keep the inserted newlines. Moreover I would recommend to avoid assembly blocks, they don't work at compile-time and they are hard to read and maintain too. What is the problem you are trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: I've been writing some compiler intrinsics for new ultra-lightweight wrappers round single x86-64 instructions to be used in a library aimed at GDC users. The functions allow zero-overhead insertion of, eg haswell, instructions inline in application code, and can even mate up seamlessly with the invoking code using the full range if addressing modes available to a new instruction.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I forgot about the alternative literal string styles. I'm a very experienced professional asm and C programmer, but new to D. I also wanted to parameter use a template to allow the selection of AT&T syntax or Intel syntax in a friendlier form as a parameter to the template, which I didn't mention in the original post. Which I would assume would  mean more concatenation. (or mixins?)

Comment: Basically, my question boils down to two parts? 1. Can strings be concatenated at compile-time? And: 2. How might mixins be exploited here, if relevant?

Comment: 1) sure and D makes it so easy that you don't really see it: `enum myString = "a" ~"b";`

Comment: I realise I didn't explain that very well. I wrote a function that took an array of literal strings, so that should hopefully have been a compile-time constant, passed the array to a function which concatenated them. GDC generated a call to a runtime library function to do the concatenation, so there was no chance of getting the _function_ to be CTFE. (So

Comment: I wasn't directly concatenating literal strings.

Comment: and many thanks for your patience btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDC is buggy in that the *AssemblerTemplate* in extended inline ASM is *supposed* to be a compile-time generate string, but actually isn't. What you *can* do is generate the string, put all the ASM stuff around it, and mix it in. I've been using something similar for a custom syscall implementation (which still inlines).

```
module test;

template joinASMStatements(T...) {
    static if (T.length == 0) enum joinASMStatements = "";
    else static if (T.length == 1) enum joinASMStatements = T[0];
    else enum joinASMStatements = joinASMStatements!(T[0..$/2]) ~ "\\n\\t" ~  joinASMStatements!(T[$/2..$]);
}

void main() {
    ulong dst, src = 20;
    enum statements = joinASMStatements!("mov %[dst], %[src]");
    mixin("asm {" ~ statements ~ " : [dst] \"rm,r\" dst : [src] \"ri,rmi\" src }");
}
```

But frankly, that looks horrifying. It would be easier and more aesthetically pleasing to create a template to handle all of this for you, which takes an array of strings. You could implement extra stuffs in the template for handling certain opcodes and adding constraints automatically based on them. That would enable the code to work on DMD and LDC too, if you wanted it to. And you can use a bit of compile-time magic to work this all out. (EDIT) This actually works.

```
module test2;

import std.traits: AliasSeq;

// Input operand type
struct IOp(string _name) {
    string constraints; // A set of constraints. This is the whole thing.
    string asmName; // A label to be given to the operand (the "[<name>]" thing)
    enum name = _name; // Inner usage, to ease accessing `_name`.
}

// Output operand type
struct OOp(string _name) {
    // For variable details, see IOp comments.
    string constraints;
    string asmName;
    enum name = _name;
}

// type for register (and "cc" and "memory") clobbers
struct Clobber(string _reg) {enum reg = _reg;}

// type for goto labels
struct Goto(string _goto) {enum name = _goto;} // note that `goto` is a D keyword.

// filters out types as S!(string blah)
template filterOp(alias S, T...) {
    static if (T.length == 0) alias filterOp = AliasSeq!();
    else static if (T.length == 1) {
        static if (is(typeof(T[0]) : S!(N), string N))
            alias filterOp = AliasSeq!(T[0]);
        else
            alias filterOp = AliasSeq!();
    } else
        alias filterOp = AliasSeq!(filterOp!(S, T[0..$/2]), filterOp!(S, T[$/2..$]));
}

// joiner function for input and output operands.
template joinOps(T...) {
    static if (T.length == 0) enum joinOps = "";
    else static if (T.length == 1) enum joinOps = ((T[0].asmName != "")?"[" ~ T[0].asmName ~ "] ":"") ~ "\"" ~ T[0].constraints ~ "\" " ~ T[0].name; // The .name unescapes the name
    else enum joinOps = joinOps!(T[0..$/2]) ~ ", " ~ joinOps!(T[$/2..$]);
}

// joiner function for clobbers
template joinClobbers(T...) {
    static if (T.length == 0) enum joinClobbers = "";
    else static if (T.length == 1) enum joinClobbers = "\"" ~ T[0].reg ~ "\"";
    else enum joinClobbers = joinClobbers!(T[0..$/2]) ~ ", " ~ joinClobbers!(T[$/2..$]);
}

// joiner function for goto labels
template joinGotos(T...) {
    static if (T.length == 0) enum joinGotos = "";
    else static if (T.length == 1) enum joinGotos = T[0].name; // Here the label is unescaped
    else enum joinGotos = joinGotos!(T[0..$/2]) ~ ", " ~ joinGotos!(T[$/2..$]); // Recursively executes itself on halves of the input. Eventually, the halves become lengths of `1` or `0`, and they are actually evaluated.
}

// joiner function for instructions.
template joinInstrs(string[] instrs) {
    static if (instrs.length == 0) enum joinInstrs = "";
    else static if (instrs.length == 1) enum joinInstrs = instrs[0];
    else enum joinInstrs = joinInstrs!(instrs[0..$/2]) ~ "\\n\\t" ~ joinInstrs!(instrs[$/2..$]);
}

// complete assembly generator function. Output is to be mixed in.
template ASM(string[] ops, T...) {
    enum iops = joinOps!(filterOp!(IOp, T));
    enum oops = joinOps!(filterOp!(OOp, T));
    enum clobbers = joinClobbers!(filterOp!(Clobber, T));
    enum gotos = joinGotos!(filterOp!(Goto, T));
    enum instrs = "\"" ~ joinInstrs!(ops) ~ "\"";
    enum ASM = "asm { " ~ instrs ~ " : " ~ oops ~ " : " ~ iops ~ " : " ~ clobbers ~ " : " ~ gotos ~ "; }";
}

void main() {
    ulong src = 24, dst;
    mixin(ASM!(["mov %[dst], %[src]"], IOp!"src"("ri,rmi", "src"), OOp!"dst"("=rm,r", "dst")));
}
```

NOTES:

- Instead of adding `=` to output constraints, you may want to combine `IOp` and `OOp` and differentiate input and output based on constraints (see the GCC docs for output constraints that work). Everything else would constitute input operands under the shared `struct Op` or similar.

  - This is my first-try attempt, and there *are* better ways to do this and to simplify the code that I have overlooked.

BTW, thanks for making me think of this! I need to implement it for my own stuff now.